# Hide a div when another div is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I know this question has been asked in other topics but for some reason I can't get this code to work on my WordPress website.

```js
if ($(".objectA").html().length == 0) {
  $("#objectB").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="objectA"></div>
<div id="objectB">hide this div</div>
```

I really don't understand why #objectB is not hidden on my page. When I check the code with developer tools I can see it's there.

Comment: this is works fine.

Comment: The element still exists; it just does not show. If you want to remove the element from the DOM, use the [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/#remove-selector) function.

Comment: it took me some time to get it....but i think the OP is asking why this snippet is working here while it is not in his local project....@k-Dushi this really cannot be answered as long as you give us only valid code. you need to reproduce the issue right here in a minimalistic way

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
if ($(".objectA").html().length == 0) {
    $("#objectB").hide();
}
```

With:

```
if (!$(".objectA").html()) {
    $("#objectB").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding document ready function. no need to click, document ready runs after page loads.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   if ($(".objectA").html().length == 0) {
       $("#objectB").hide();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After Googling a bit more I found the solution myself.

WordPress doesn't accept just `if($` ... It needs `jQuery(function ($) {` before the function. Like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    if($(".empty-div").html().length ==0)
    {
    $("#deals-wrapper, .listing-details li.vc_tta-tab:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+3)").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Make sure that jQuery is loaded **before** your own script.